# SIGABRT 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Собственно есть код и если картинка не загруженна(отсутствует), при зуммировании получается SIGABRT:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
```

Как быть и что делать?

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *img;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property NSString *downloadedimage;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents;
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 5.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_downloadedimage];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    self.imageView.image=_img;
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=_img.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = _img.size;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showHideNavbar:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

}

-(void) showHideNavbar:(id) sender
{
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"DetailView";
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берешь UIImageView, засовываешь ее в UIScrollView. Задаешь фрейм для имеджа:

```
self.imageView.frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
```

Задаешь для имеджа http://take.ms/XawTm , а для скролла http://take.ms/QnoKD можно и больше трех, но как по мне - с головой.

Это в viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapAction:)];
    doubleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[self.view setGestureRecognizers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doubleTapGest, nil]];
```

Добавляешь метод для возврата в первый скэйл.

```
- (void)doubleTapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
}
```

Вроде все.

Не все, забыл: если твой imageView.image == nil , то у scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

p.s. если не секрет, SIGABRT - это просто crash? )

Answer (score 0):

Смотреть фреймы всех вьюшек (например перед зумом), скорей всего у какой-то какая-то координата и/или размер как раз NaN.